# server version when inserting to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a library that using twilio for sms and nuget from that library, now i am using this in my asp.net core web application and i am able to send the message that works fine, however i cant save it to the database. I get this error, however i can see all my history migrations in my db

```
ServerVersion = '((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)_context.Database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

    [ActionName("MessageStatus")]
    public ActionResult Send(Message message)
    {
        var viewModel = new MessageViewModel
        {
            Message = new Message(),
         };
        _context.Messages.Add(message);
         _messageSender.Send(message);
        return View("MessageStatus", viewModel);
    }
my appDBContext
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }

service dependendies json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mssql1": {
      "type": "mssql",
      "connectionId": "dbConnection"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `_context` is a `DbContext`, you're not saving to the database at any point. You're missing a `_context.SaveChanges();` call after adding the message

Comment: Do you get any error? I see you are not calling `_context.SaveChanges()`, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: i have tried that, and no error either

Comment: only thing is that when i expand _context there is CurrentTransaction = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

Comment: Ok my bad.. andother ServerVersion = '((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)_context.Database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'